# mysql batch insert

Tags: mysql, insert, bulkinsert, batch-insert

I am doing batch insert for inserting 80k records and 1200 records per batch. 
The query is executing fine. The problem is that I am getting data from mssql server and creating a batch array out of it. So there are changes are due to some reason one of the batch insert fails.

But when a batch insert fails, it does for all 1200 records of that particular batch.

So, is there any way to find out how to get the exact records from the batch of 1200 records that failed the batch insertion.

And one more question.

While doing these insertion, the web site goes down for the time of updation.

Is there any way that during this time as well the site is not down.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply but logs files will show the batch query means insert into table(columns) values (),(),().... . Not which particular insert caused the batch to fail.

Comment: there must be an error line somewhere in the log files, based on that you can hunt down the batch and find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tools will give you more performance, as your bottleneck is your server...
what you can do to lower the server load is either to use transactions, or use "insert delayed".

Transaction: [ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/...-commands.html ]
If your db support it (mysql may need a specific backend to support it, depending of mysql version), you start a transaction by sending "start tansaction", then send all your insert one after the other, and finish the transaction with a "commit" or a "rollback".
This method have the great advantage that the db knows that it don't have to re-compute the indexes before you do the commit.

insert delayed: [ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/...t-delayed.html ]
This is a special mysql command, that let you give a hint on the db about the importance of the insert.
An insert delayed will always be processed when the db will not be occupied doing something else, it have a low priority comparing to standard insert/update.

Comment: Thanks Wasim for your reply. There is a problem with transaction, I can't used it. And for insert delayed, my site is a product selling and auction site. And insert delay does not guarantee you the time when actual insert will be done, So the changes to product cost and auction will not be reflected instantly. So I didn't go for it.

Comment: Is there any tool, of course free one that show the mysql server load and time etc

Comment: So do it by script in programming language you are using. Apply appropriated checks and handle errors.

Comment: I am doing scripting and doing batch insert of 2k rows in single query. but how do I come to know that which single records from 2k batch triggered the batch insert.